# Create a Map of String in Java for an Adapter

Tags: android, dictionary, expandablelistview

Hi I'm developing an Android application in which I need to use the expandable list. I found on the web a good sample code to use the expandable list. So I based on this code to solve my problem.
The result should be similar to my iOS app, you can see the screenshot here: http://postimg.org/image/ej9t50f6t/.
I'm in this situation:
the key of my Map is inserted in an array, the data is inserted in 2 arrays, now I should have this situation:

```
Map {
key = Episodio 1       29 Giu 2013, value= [14:30, https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-XSh-9ngYJu4/ThiY-xl2EeI/AAAAAAAABmc/iz04VpL5hOs/s800/realtime.png, Real Time]

key = Episodio 1       29 Giu 2013, value= [16:30, http://tv.zam.it/canali/dmax.png, DMAX]

key = Episodio 2       01 Lug 2013, value= [14:30, https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-XSh-9ngYJu4/ThiY-xl2EeI/AAAAAAAABmc/iz04VpL5hOs/s800/realtime.png, Real Time]

key = Episodio 2       01 Lug 2013, value= [16:30, http://tv.zam.it/canali/dmax.png, DMAX]
}
```

So I wrote this code:

```
    String[] progrepvis1 = null;
    String[] progrepvis2 = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < epTime.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            String[] progrepvis1temp = {epTime[i], epChLogo[i], epCh[i]};
            progrepvis1 = progrepvis1temp;
        } else {
            String[] progrepvis2temp = {epTime[i], epChLogo[i], epCh[i]};
            progrepvis2 = progrepvis2temp;
        }
    }
    episodeData = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

    Log.d("GROUP", "" + groupList);

    for (String episode : groupList) {
        for (int i = 0; i < episodeNumberAndDate.length; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0 && episode.equals(episodeNumberAndDate[i])) {
                loadChild(progrepvis1);
            } else {
                loadChild(progrepvis2);
            }
        }
        episodeData.put(episode, childList);
    }
    Log.d("LISTA", "" + episodeData);

}

private void loadChild(String[] episodeData) {
    childList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String episode : episodeData) {
        childList.add(episode);
    }
}
```

But the result of this snippet is the follow:

```
Map {
key = Episodio 1       29 Giu 2013, value= [16:30, http://tv.zam.it/canali/dmax.png, DMAX]

key = Episodio 2       01 Lug 2013, value= [16:30, http://tv.zam.it/canali/dmax.png, DMAX]
}
```

You can see that I've only the repetition of the programs but I've not the first time, how I can fix this problem? I hope you can help me
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem lies with the fact that your keys are identical, which in the case of a HashMap will group the identical keys into a single key/value pair (with the last added value overwritting previously added values).

If you want to be able to use the same key multiple times, try something like this:

```
HashMap<String, Vector<String>> keyValueList = new HashMap<String, Vector<String>>();
```

This is a `HashMap` with a `String` as the key, and using a `Vector<String>` as the *value*. This vector will allow you to have multiple values for a single key.

To read the values from this *list*:

```
String key = "Episodio 1       29 Giu 2013";
Vector<String> valueList = keyValueList.get(key);
for ( int i = 0; i < valueList.getSize(); i++ )
{
    String value = valueList.elementAt(i);
    // ... do something with the value here
}
```

Comment: I understand my stupid problem, now I will try to fix by adding an identifier to my key

Answer (score 0):

From Java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

> **public interface Map**
>
> An object that maps keys to values. A map ***CANNOT*** contain duplicate
>   keys; each key can map to at most one value.

You are trying to have different values mapped to same key, it is not possible.

> **put(K key, V value)**
>   Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map (optional operation).

So when you call `episodeData.put(episode, childList);` 2nd time with the same key, you are overwriting the value from the 1st time.

Comment: I'm stupid... I understand my idiot error... I will try to fix it maybe adding something to the first and to the second key...